# Error: redirect_uri_mismatch google calendar

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, calendar

I am trying to connect to google calendar but seems to send me an error like this 
**400. That’s an error.**
**Error: redirect_uri_mismatch**

My url for site is http://example.lvh.me:3000/

Help me !!!! Thanks!

[image: Error Message Print]

Answer (score 1):

Please check following steps to resolve issue

1. Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
   as the following error, copy the following link text
   The redirect URI in the request, **http://example.lvh.me:3000/**, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit
2. Login into Google Console Api, go to Credential, Choose your Api and past the above link to Authorized redirect URIs section
3. Save and test again